# Leaflet sidebar v2 how to not expand tab when click on button

Tags: plugins, leaflet, sidebar

I'm using leaflet sidebar v2 and I need to have a button in sidebar that allows user to active control to click over map to get a poppup. That it works, but tab is expanded without content, and this is not necesary, in fact, in mobiles screen, is better not expand tab.

Is possible to click over a button in sidebar "collapsed" and continue "collapsed"?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I got it myself :)

Just changing the "normal" code to add a sidebar's button:

```
<li><a href="#info" role="tab"><i class="fa fa-info"></i></a></li>
```

To:

```
<li><a class="customButtonSideBar"><i class="fa fa-info"></i></a></li>
```

Pay attention, the diference is eliminate href attribute of a element, then add a jquery click binding to control the action:

```
$('.customButtonSideBar').click(function(){
...your code...
});
```